# Gitlab-CI PHP executable returning error code 255

Tags: php, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I recently set up GitLab-CI in my self-hosted GitLab CE instance. I created one runner for a specific project and one shared runner.

My `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` is following:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "project runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.domain.com/ci"
  token = "SECRET"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "geertw/docker-php-ci:7.0-no-xdebug"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]

[[runners]]
  name = "shared runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.domain.com"
  token = "SECRET"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "geertw/docker-php-ci:7.0-no-xdebug"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Then I added custom scripts to my `composer.json` file:

```
...

"scripts": {
    "build": [
        "@composer install --no-progress --no-interaction --no-suggest",
        "@lint"
    ],
    "lint": "php -d display_errors -d display_startup_errors ./vendor/bin/parallel-lint --exclude vendor ."
}
```

And the script is part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  - php -v

services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "database"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"

build:7.0:
  image: geertw/docker-php-ci:7.0
  script:
    - composer build
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never

build:7.1:
  image: geertw/docker-php-ci:7.1-no-xdebug
  script:
    - composer build

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
```

When I execute the pipeline in GitLab, I receive an error:

```
> php -d display_errors -d display_startup_errors ./vendor/bin/parallel-lint --exclude vendor .
Script php -d display_errors -d display_startup_errors ./vendor/bin/parallel-lint --exclude vendor . handling the lint event returned with error code 255
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Now when I run `composer lint` locally, it works as expected. I also tried to comment it out and I receive the same error with PHPUnit (build:7.0 in .gitlab-ci.yml). For debugging reasons I added `php -d` to display errors, yet nothing is shown.

The other (private) pipeline works as expected for a smaller project that has exactly the same `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. I also tried switching from one runner to another but it doesn't work on either.

Since I am new to docker and CI in general, I have little knowledge on how to debug this situation properly, perhaps increase php memory_limit
in some way or output errors to stderr.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can the source of parallel-lint give you any hints?: https://github.com/JakubOnderka/PHP-Parallel-Lint/blob/master/parallel-lint.php

Comment: Also; Is display_errors etc. on in your containers php.ini? Maybe thats why no errors are displayed?

Comment: I am using default gitlab-ci php 7 containers and honestly I don't know if there is display_errors enabled. But I have added the `php -d` which adds directive to display all errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an autoloader executing ext-mysqli functions with @call. The app is a mess.